# Persistable collection hash codes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hash

Please see the objects below. What I need to do is query the entity framework for instances of MyObject that contain a specific collection of Option. For instance, I want all MyObject where the Options collection contains Option Id = 1 & Options Id = 5 and no other options.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //... More Properties

    public IEnumerable<Option> Options { get; }
}

public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking of trying to implement some sort of option hash and persisting it. Then, my query would be "where MyObject.OptionHash == [HASH]". As far as I can tell, typical hash algorithms cannot generate a guaranteed unique hash. Any input or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: Yeah, I get that I can't make a unique numeric hash. I was thinking more along the lines of something like: OptionsHash = Options.Select(o => o.Id.ToString()).Aggregate((hash, id) => hash + "-" + id); I guess I'm using the word hash incorrectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do it.

```
var itemsToCheck = new int[] {1, 5};
var filtered = myObjects.Where(myObject => !myObject.Options.Except(itemsToCheck).Any())
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used Except before. I need to profile and see what SQL is generated from this.

Comment: @DaleAlleshouse out of curiosity, what SQL did it generate?